# How do I launch a process with low priority? C#

Tags: c#, process, shellexecute

I want to execute a command line tool to process data. It does not need to be blocking.
I want it to be low priority. So I wrote the below

```
 Process app = new Process();
 app.StartInfo.FileName = @"bin\convert.exe";
 app.StartInfo.Arguments = TheArgs;
 app.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;
 app.Start();
```

However, I get a `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message "No process is associated with this object." Why? How do I properly launch this app in low priority?

Without the line `app.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;` the app runs fine.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try setting the PriorityClass AFTER you start the process.  Task Manager works this way, allowing you to set priority on a process that is already running.

Comment: Turns out this is the only way.

Comment: As pointed out by Alois Kraus this gives a race condition. The fact that this is the way it is designed to be done by Microsoft does not make it any less a very BAD idea.

Comment: Race condition or not, I don't see the problem here.  The process would *momentarily* be running in the parent process's priority.

Comment: It is actually a big problem. I get occasions when this moment is long enough for the process to complete. I thus end up with an intermittent run time crash when it tries to set the priority of a finished process. This is a serious design flaw.

Answer (score 16):

You can create a process with lower priority by doing a little hack. You lower the parent process priority, create the new process and then revert back to the original process priority:

```
var parent   = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var original = parent.PriorityClass;

parent.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;
var child            = Process.Start("cmd.exe");
parent.PriorityClass = original;
```

`child` will have the `Idle` process priority right at the start.

Comment: That is by far the best solution with no races. The other solutions need to wait until the process is running which can be an issue if you start e.g. a script which starts other child processes which will then run with the initial priority and not the one you will set later.

Comment: I really don't like this, but I like debugging intermittent errors less.

Turns out this is actually the only way.

Answer (score 7):

If you're prepared to P/Invoke to `CreateProcess`, you can pass `CREATE_SUSPENDED` in the flags. Then you can tweak the process priority before resuming the process.