# How to set priority of another application in c#

Tags: c#, taskmanager

How should I set the priority of a different application running on the computer in c# win form. I'm a little new to this website and coding all together.

```c#
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe","wmic process where name=\"HD-Frontend.exe\" CALL setpriority 32");
```

Is what I've tried so far. Just didn't work... :(

Comment: It seems odd to have to change the priority, what have you attempted so far that has not worked to achieve your goal?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "wmic process where name=\"HD-Frontend.exe\" CALL setpriority 32");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setpriority 32 appears to be a linux call

What you need to do is get the Process handle from Start like this

```
Process myProcess = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "wmic process where name=\"HD-Frontend.exe\"");
```

Then play with the priority once you have the handle

```
myProcess.PriorityClass = RealTime;
```

Alternatively, you could define your process before starting it and edit the priority before it has started

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.PriorityClass = RealTime;
myProcess.Start();
```

Look at the [ProcessPriority property of Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Says that RealTime doesn't Exist.

Comment: Try putting System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass. in front of RealTime

Comment: not sure, is there any reason you start wmic inside cmd.exe? Why don't you just start wmic

Comment: Set the `PriorityClass` property *after* you start the process for the priority to work. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010377/2638227).